# Clear roaming setting in winrt application

Tags: .net, windows-runtime

I am writing a winrt application using VS2012.

To detect application first time startup I am using a variable saved using roaming settings. If the specified setting is missing or have wrong value my application performs a initial setup sequence.

During development in VS2012 I have the need to clear this setting so the application performs a initial start.

I have found now way to do this,,,? How do I remove roaming settings for a application?

//lg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `[Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.ClearAsync method][1]` that lets you specify a locality, in this case [Windows.Storage.ApplicationLocality.Roaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdatalocality.aspx).

This will clear everything out of roaming appdata and also flush the cloud, as I understand it. You can certainly reset individual values too, but ClearAsync is the most complete means.

Comment: Two simular answers.  I had hoped for a solution not involving coding,, do something from the desktop.

Comment: Ah, didn't know you were asking about doing it outside the app. IN that case you have two options. (1) go to %localappdata%\packages\<your package>\ and clear out the Settings folder and the RoamingState folder. This is what the ClearAsync method essentially does. (2) From the Start screen, uninstall the app. This will clear out all app data folders. Either way, you get a clean slate on the next run from VS.

Comment: <your package>,, can you lock this name. Seems to me that VS generates names at will,,, and copies content ... or??

Comment: The package moniker, as it's called is a combination of your app's Store ID (a number + your publisher name), followed by .<app name> then _<publisher hash>. The <app name> comes from your manifest's package name (on the packaging tab in the manifest editor), and the hash is generated from your publisher certificate string. So long as these values remain fixed, the moniker will stay the same. Plus, in the manifest editor, the Package Family Name field contains exactly this string. If the app isn't published to the Store yet, it won't have the publisher ID at the front.

Comment: @KraigBrockschmidt-MSFT I am having a similar problem and I created a method
`private static async void clearData ()
    {
        await ApplicationData.ClearAsync();
    }`
But it is showing me error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'ApplicationData.ClearAsync()'"

Comment: @KraigBrockschmidt-MSFT I solved the problem. I was missing 'Current` in between `ApplicationData.Current.ClearAsync();`.

Answer (score 1):

I would just conditionally include code that removes the setting:

```
#if RESET_APP
roamingSettings.Values.Remove("exampleSetting");
#endif
```